# Como restar una misma variable dentro de un while con php

Tags: php, mysql, while

tengo la siguiente consulta estoy usando php:

```
<?php
$rendillan="SELECT id_repa,tipo_rep_equiv,nro_reparacion,km_repa,tipo_dano,zona_repa,duracion,COUNT(*) as id_repa FROM reparacion where nro_cliente_repa='$llantap' group by nro_reparacion";                   
$rent=mysql_query($rendillan,$con);
?>


<table border='1'> 
<tr>
<th>Repair Number</th>
<th>Life Repaired</th>
<th>Type Repair</th>
<th>Type of Damage</th>
<th>Damage location</th>
<th>Fail</th>
<th>Repair Duration</th>
</tr>
<?php
while(($rentl=mysql_fetch_assoc($rent))>0)
{
    $tipo=$rentl['tipo_dano'];



?>
<tr>
<td><b><?php echo $rentl['nro_reparacion']; ?></b></td>
<td><b><?php echo round($rentl['km_repa']); ?></b></td>
<td><b><?php echo $rentl['tipo_rep_equiv']; ?></b></td>
<td><b><?php echo $rentl['tipo_dano']; ?></b></td>
<td><b><?php echo $rentl['zona_repa']; ?></b></td>

<?php if($tipo=='Falla de Reparacion')
{ 
echo "<td style='background-color:red;'><b>SI</b></td>";
}
else{ 
echo "<td style='background-color:#ffffff;'><b>NO</b></td>";
} ?>

<td><b>Aquí va la variable que deseo calcular</b></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Ahora la columna de la tabla que se llama -Repair Duration- allí debo calcular cuanto duro cada reparación.

Y se calcula de la siguiente manera:

Registro 1 = 24824 (Esta variable es: km_repa)
registro 2 = 49992 (Esta variable es: km_repa)

49992-24824 = 25168

como puedo hacer para que dentro del while haga ese calculo y luego imprimir la variable en la columna -Repair Duration-.

Ya intente restando la variable km_repa con la misma pero siempre me da 0

la idea es recorrer el while y que me vaya dando el valor correcto.

Cualquier ayuda es de gran utilidad.

Ya realice los ajustes quedando la consulta de esta manera:

```
<?php
$rendillan="SELECT id_repa,tipo_rep_equiv,nro_reparacion,km_repa,tipo_dano,zona_repa,duracion,COUNT(*) as id_repa FROM reparacion where nro_cliente_repa='$llantap' group by nro_reparacion";                   
$rent=mysql_query($rendillan,$con);
?>


<table border='1'> 
<tr>
<th>Repair Number</th>
<th>Life Repaired</th>
<th>Type Repair</th>
<th>Type of Damage</th>
<th>Damage location</th>
<th>Fail</th>
<th>Repair Duration</th>
</tr>
<?php
$km_repa = 0;
$resultado = 0;
while(($rentl=mysql_fetch_assoc($rent))>0)
{
    $tipo=$rentl['tipo_dano'];

    $km_repa = $rentl['km_repa'];
    $resultado = $km_repa - $resultado; //Almacenas la resta

?>
<tr>
<td><b><?php echo $rentl['nro_reparacion']; ?></b></td>
<td><b><?php echo round($rentl['km_repa']); ?></b></td>
<td><b><?php echo $rentl['tipo_rep_equiv']; ?></b></td>
<td><b><?php echo $rentl['tipo_dano']; ?></b></td>
<td><b><?php echo $rentl['zona_repa']; ?></b></td>

<?php if($tipo=='Falla de Reparacion')
{ 
echo "<td style='background-color:red;'><b>SI</b></td>";
}
else{ 
echo "<td style='background-color:#ffffff;'><b>NO</b></td>";
} ?>

<td><b>Aquí va la variable que deseo calcular</b></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
```

Y la columna da como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que me esta dando mal los resultados.

Comment: Declara una variable global y resultado. Asignas en el while a la variable global el registro y luego $resultado =  $variable - $resultado;

Comment: Hola @Eric puedes hacer un ejemplo con lo que tengo para ver de manera lo podria aplicar por favor :) muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaras las variables globales como te dejé el comentario.

Dentro del while obtienes el valor de `km_repa` y en la variable `$resultado` almacenarías la resta.

```
<?php
    $km_repa = 0;
    $resultado = 0;
    while(($rentl=mysql_fetch_assoc($rent))>0)
    {
        $km_repa = round($rentl['km_repa']); //Asignas el valor de km_repa 
        $resultado = $km_repa - $resultado; //Almacenas la resta
    }
?>
```

Si obtienes el resultado negativo puedes manejar el valor absoluto para valores positivos.

Comment: ya edite mi pregunta con los resultados, pero creo que esta dando resultados erróneos para que la oberves por favor.

Comment: Faltaría encerar la variable resultado después de 2 iteracciones.

Comment: se puede encerrar de la siguiente manera? $resultado = 2;

Comment: Puede ser otra variable global que se incrementa dentro del while. if $count % 2 == 0 { $resultado = 0; }. Con el módulo para saber si es múltiplo de 2.